# Counting the number of leading zero bits in a sha256 encrpytion

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to count the number of leading zero bits after an sha256 hash function as I don't have a lot of experience on 'low level' stuff in python

```
hex = hashlib.sha256((some_data_from_file).encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
# hex = 0000094e7cc7303a3e33aaeaba76ad937603d4d040064f473a12f10ab30a879f
# this has 20 leading zero bits
hex_digits = int.from_bytes(bytes(hex.encode('ascii')), 'big') #convert str to int

#count num of leading zeroes 
def countZeros(x):
   total_bits = 256
   res = 0
   while ((x & (1 << (total_bits - 1))) == 0):
       x = (x << 1)
       res += 1
   return res
print(countZeroes(hex_digits)) # returns 2
```

I've also tried converting it using `bin()` however that didn't provide me with any leading zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of getting the **hex** digest and analyzing that hex string, you could just get the **digest**, interpret it as an int, ask for its bit-length, and subtract that from 256:

```
digest = hashlib.sha256(some_data_from_file.encode('ascii')).digest()
print(256 - int.from_bytes(digest, 'big').bit_length())
```

Demo ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY5BTsMwEEX3PsVILGxL4EVRQzc9RQ8Q2ckkHsnxRPagNlw@GAosECt2o6///pt1k8j5@bSWfadl5SIQfY2JglKVF@xHL76fCi/9RAnhDLrrji@ng1bqAS6RrxDxBiPNWAUmLjAkX0g29RGfv8dcjf5w7Mwfkw7zwCMa7etApK11jbzvGavWQllMS@yPL78uAQvwBAn9SHmGNywMgaSqrz/@5/0lbRw8QbvcJxM2wWrunUfQgWZtXZP2CfMs0Vi77@8)):

```
import hashlib

some_data_from_file = '665782'

# Show hex digest for clarity
hex = hashlib.sha256(some_data_from_file.encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
print(hex)

# Show number of leading zero bits
digest = hashlib.sha256(some_data_from_file.encode('ascii')).digest()
print(256 - int.from_bytes(digest, 'big').bit_length())
```

Output:

```
0000000399c6aea5ad0c709a9bc331a3ed6494702bd1d129d8c817a0257a1462
30
```

Benchmark along with Pranav's (not sure how to handle mtraceur's) starting with `sha256`-values (i.e., before calling `hexdigest()` or `digest()`):

```
 462 ns   464 ns   471 ns  just_digest
 510 ns   518 ns   519 ns  just_hexdigest
 566 ns   568 ns   574 ns  Kelly3
 608 ns   608 ns   611 ns  Kelly2
 688 ns   688 ns   692 ns  Kelly
1139 ns  1139 ns  1140 ns  Pranav
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVTRjpswEHz3V6xOOsW@UkqS6ymNxBf0pe9RhAxsglsw1Haqy/18amOTAM1V6kuRIoIzOzM7u6Q7m6qV602nLpcSD/AV6/pMdcVXn1/YloC9FJqTkmAP4CMIaeKDapssPxvUARiX4ojaUBbBIhfHBYtzYbIa5dFUlBFyJV5Nmd9QtRpSSPqnQ6vAsVoNmPF6uLvEocfcDkYOPd0H2FifDjR1MYADKoUNmdeOnK6nTr0Ra3VmjIw8wTYNuF2yvxkMAu@bej8Fz/Zfm/@muOS/ps3LPx0WoyFV@Hp3TgWkKTwkD9uBwMo@XwFYa9zCpBPLIlzGdsdoEUHONabLFzbBjKhso7ThpooPddsq/7Vujyva8zBmw1hOi3OF/Me4cTnq/PtJmyw0cm//55O/Fd0C@EvdKCVCDidZuEBHmtGMKwp7GO6rcI/ChCyHfQvBiAZtZqLpWmWsYofckPBUcV3VIo/AJePhRVvXWBjRSj3UlPjzhIR4l87TLtTF/ohqo6hgMcqiLZEuuC6EWLBJsG4jhNsIa@2IdJlkSZKwPSH42lk5S1oL23jDOxqaCHKWxtW6OFx5H8sQnj7Vk0r347jQoTrldmXApuD1op4ozjLJG8wym7fRfWe7fW81u2rtyfV5sB6G55nZdeG9utEO@ia8G@0O9Gjpnd9GSOrnQGve5CXf@ojv9BBBYj/y1OSo0uUoUqNj3nUoS2r@0YG3/UQXj88l2CEv4BGogU9g/wnooAtPsMQvrGc1/YtsFwGtmGa77XrP5vldLr8B)):

```
def Kelly(sha256):
    return 256 - int.from_bytes(sha256.digest(), 'big').bit_length()

def Kelly2(sha256):
    zeros = 0
    for byte in sha256.digest():
        if byte:
            return zeros + 8 - byte.bit_length()
        zeros += 8
    return zeros

def Kelly3(sha256):
    digest = sha256.digest()
    if byte := digest[0]:
        return 8 - byte.bit_length()
    zeros = 0
    for byte in digest:
        if byte:
            return zeros + 8 - byte.bit_length()
        zeros += 8
    return zeros

def Pranav(sha256):
    nzeros = 0
    for c in sha256.hexdigest():
        if c == "0": nzeros += 4
        else: 
            digit = int(c, base=16)
            nzeros += 4 - (math.floor(math.log2(digit)) + 1)
            break
    return nzeros

def just_digest(sha256):
    return sha256.digest()

def just_hexdigest(sha256):
    return sha256.hexdigest()

funcs = just_digest, just_hexdigest, Kelly3, Kelly2, Kelly, Pranav

from timeit import repeat
import hashlib, math
from collections import deque

sha256s = [hashlib.sha256(str(i).encode('ascii'))
           for i in range(10_000)]

expect = list(map(Kelly, sha256s))
for func in funcs:
    result = list(map(func, sha256s))
    print(result == expect, func.__name__)

tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(10):
    print()
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        t = min(repeat(lambda: deque(map(func, sha256s), 0), number=1))
        ts.append(t)
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        print(*('%4d ns ' % (t / len(sha256s) * 1e9) for t in sorted(ts)[:3]), func.__name__)
```

Comment: Bit length! Nice, I forgot about that. If `int.from_bytes` and `bit_length` is trusted to be side-channel-safe for an initially fixed-byte-length input, that's vastly simpler than my hand-cobbled attempt at a "secure" version.

Comment: I hooked a couple of mine into your test setup, and my first two seem comparable to Pranav's (`bin`-based is a bit slower, the bitwise loop a bit faster), while my attempt at a "secure" implementation is painfully glacially slower, like more than 10 times slower (I think ~70 times slower but I already closer it and can't remember). Probably not too worth including mine.

Comment: @mtraceur Ok, I'll leave them out then. I also wasn't comfortable with leaving your `(1 << max_bits) - 1` in your code for benchmarking, but generally try to not modify other people's code too much, either. No surprise that your "secure" one is much slower, given that it needs to slow all cases down to the worst case time :-)

Comment: Tell me more about the discomfort with `(1 << max_bits) - 1`?

Comment: @mtraceur `maxbits` is fixed for their problem (its value is 256), so it would be faster to compute `(1 << 256) - 1` at compile-time. It would feel unfair to compute it in the benchmark. And probably actually the whole line shouldn't be there.

Comment: Re: "needs to slow all cases down to the worst case time" I think the worst case time would still be tiny if it weren't for the Python overheads, it's the Python overheads that explode by several times because of manually stepping through every byte and every bit of every byte in Python.

Comment: Re: the max bits: ah, yeah, you're right, that could've been compile-time constant and optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

## Danger!!!

Is this security-sensitive code? Can this hash ever be the result of hashing secret/private data?

If so, then you should probably implement something in C or similar, while taking care to protect against leaking information about the hash through side-channels.

Otherwise, I suggest picking the version (from any of these answers) that *you and the people working on your code* find the most intuitive, clear, and so on, unless performance matters more than readability, in which case pick the fastest one.

---

If your hashes are never of security-sensitive inputs, then:

If you just want a good balance of simplicity and low-effort:

```py
def count_leading_zeroes(value, max_bits=256):
    value &= (1 << max_bits) - 1  # truncate; treat negatives as 2's compliment
    if value == 0:
        return max_bits
    significant_bits = len(bin(value)) - 2  # has "0b" prefix
    return max_bits - significant_bits
```

If you want to really embrace the bit twiddling you were trying in your question:

```py
def count_leading_zeroes(value, max_bits=256):
   top_bit = 1 << (max_bits - 1)
   count = 0
   value &= (1 << max_bits) - 1
   while not value & top_bit:
       count += 1
       value <<= 1
   return count
```

If you're doing manual bit twiddling, I think in this case a loop which counts from the top is the most justified option, because hashes are rather evenly randomly distributed and so each bit has about even chance of not being zero.

So you have a good chance of exiting the loop early and thus executing more efficiently if you start for from the top (if you start from the bottom you have to  check every bit).

You could alternatively do a bit twiddling thing that's inspired by binary search. That way instead of O(n) steps you do O(log(n)) steps. However, this arguably isn't an optimization worth doing in CPython, and for a JIT implementation like PyPy [this manual optimization can actually make it harder for automatic optimization to realize that you can just use a raw "count leading zeroes" CPU instruction](https://mentalisttraceur-software.tumblr.com/post/670614804982054912/heres-a-great-example-of-why-writing-code-which). If I ever get the time I'll edit this answer with an example of that later.

---

Now about those **side-channel attacks**: basically any time you have code that works on secret data (or any results of secret data which you can't *prove* (like a cryptographer would) have *fully* irretrievably lost all information about the secret data) , you should make sure your code takes does exactly the same amount of operations and takes the same branches regardless of the data!

Explaining *why* you should do this is outside the scope of this answer, but if you don't, your code could be harming users by leaking their secret information in ways that hackers could access.

So!

You might be tempted to modify the simple version that uses `bin`, but `bin` is inherently hash-dependent: it produces a string whose length is conditional on the leading zeroes, and as far as I know it doesn't (and logically can't! at least not in the general case) guarantee that it does so in constant-time without data-dependent branches. So we should assume merely running `bin` on an integer leaks information about the integer through side-channels like runtime and branch predictor state and amount of memory allocated and so on.

For illustrative purposes, *if* we *did* have a side-channel-safe `bin`, which I'll call "`bin_`", we could do:

```py
def count_leading_zeroes(value, max_bits=256):
    value &= (1 << max_bits) - 1  # truncate; treat negatives as 2's compliment
    value <<= 1  # securely compensate for 0
    significant_bits = len(bin_(value)) - 3  # has "0b" prefix and "0" suffix
    return max_bits - significant_bits
```

In principle, a bit-twiddling loop could do leading zero bit count in  *constant-time* and *free of input-dependent branches*.

The challenge is writing this neatly in Python, because Python is so abstracted from the underlying machine.

The core problem is this: at the CPU level, it's really easy to take a 1 or 0 bit and turn it, branchlessly, into something more useful (like a mask with all bits 1s or all bits 2s, which then lets you conditionally but branchlessly select one of two numbers or clear a number, which you can then use to implement something like "if the lowest bit is set, reset the counter to zero"). At the Python level, implementing stuff like this is a struggle through the fog of a lot of uncertainty of how the Python runtime is implemented - there are many places where it might be reasonable to have data-dependent branches under the covers. So really we want to reduce the amount of Python steps and conversions between the digest that `hashlib` gives us and our leading zeroes answer.

So the best option is actually to never even reach for human-readable stuff like hex or integer forms of the digest at all! Just stick to the raw digest. Something like this, conceptually:

```py
def count_leading_zeroes_in_bytes(data):
   count = 0
   # branchless "latch" mask to stop counting:
   still_in_leading_zeroes = 1
   for byte in data:
       for index in reversed(range(8)):
           bit = (byte >> index) & 1
           # branchless "conditional" if bit is zero:
           is_zero = bit ^ 1
           # branchlessly increment count if needed:
           count += is_zero & still_in_leading_zeroes
           # branchlessly latch count on first 1 bit:
           still_in_leading_zeroes &= is_zero
   return count
```

This is the best I was able to think of in pure Python. And it still failed.

But some quick testing by both @KellyBundy and me (see comments and Kelly's answer for some examples) shows this version is both extremely slow, and does not actually achieve input-independent execution times (because there's yet another relevant data-dependent optimization inside Python, and possibly for other reasons we're missing).

So if you're going to try to implement anything in Python, test it thoroughly before relying on it to be actually be secure, or just taking the general gist and implementing a C or assembly version. Something like this:

```c
/* _clz.c */

#include <limits.h>  /* CHAR_BIT */
#include <stddef.h>  /* size_t */

int count_leading_zeroes_bytes(char * bytes, size_t length)
{                                                           
    int still_in_leading_zeroes = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while(length--)
    {
        char byte = *bytes++;
        int bits = CHAR_BIT;
        while(bits--)
        {
            int bit = (byte >> bits) & 1;
            int is_zero = bit ^ 1;
            count += is_zero & still_in_leading_zeroes;
            still_in_leading_zeroes &= is_zero;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

```py
# clz.py

import ctypes


# This is just a quick example. A mature version
# would load the library as appropriate for each
# platform.
_library = ctypes.CDLL('./_clz.so')
_count_leading_zeroes_bytes = _library.count_leading_zeroes_bytes


def count_leading_zeroes_bytes(data):
    return _count_leading_zeroes_bytes(
        ctypes.c_char_p(data),
        ctypes.c_size_t(len(data)),
    )
```

Comment: I left yours out of my benchmark since I think you start with `value` already being an int. Should I use the same `int.from_bytes(...)` I used for my own solution?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah that's probably fine. Also I just updated my answer with at least one additional more secure solution, which works from the original digest bytes (calling `.digest()` instead of `.hexdigest()`).

Comment: Ok, will do. Your last solution btw takes about [6% longer](https://tio.run/##jZLdasMwDIXv8xSig5JsvUhbBqWQvsjYghMrrZhjB1sd614@s@K2kIuO@c76@c5B0nDhk7Pb3eDHsfOuB6YeiYH6wXkGjwMqzjKNHbTubLk2qDTZY/2D3mGoydbNhTHkWrEq9hlAqoMKSvk8QeOVbU8GQ4CFUdyeFtCr8AnsILAbUnkkTr2ByRiBzmUibS3pznkQOSALIjj1wDVBVuO3ZDx@oQ@o86h8xHxXFPc6eQ2Ju3ziHA6prYBlUri9ue/WWU1MziqzAOomBAUQczM0hclwxEvFx2OkuUTd1mOPcVRpYBFrETXqGTHlXqo7evloRn9ITWO/opyFjnxgWIvHmdaj4S/v6lLtkc/eJlo8jLgFWU86grfyvYBn2G5Wt8Dm9fUayjJZktTfthcknhzIRnqyebq33Ki@0Wr/n5NbXW@02pQrsOe@QV@ty7IoJu7gyXLOUSjGYoG0iMlx/AU) with all bits 1 than with all bits 0.

Comment: @KellyBundy if that's true because of my solution rather than other reasons then I've failed terribly, and have no idea how to make Python play nice without just dropping down into C.

Comment: Removing more and more code from the bottom of your loop reveals a [big difference at the `byte >> index` operation](https://tio.run/##jVDLboMwELzzFav0AhUHQhQpikR@pKqQgSVYxQ@tl6rpz1MvJpV6q2@encfu@AdPzp4untZ1JGeAtUHNoI13xEDoUXGWDThC7xbL7Yxq0PbefiM5DK22bfdgDPmgWBXXDCDxoIFKPi/QkbL9NGMIcJgV99MBjAofwA4CO5/o0XHTBtbzLKZ/Y6LbUcajI5A40BYkcNPAPtB2wC@ZEH4iBRzymHzH/FIUv7z4Nv3tluiCE/JCNu0RL422kpeueqveC3iFU10@gfp83qEsk1ThP9cJgqcsKcBom6cC81mZblDX/3RY7qU3dVWCXUyH1Byrqig2X0/acs4xKGKRIBJZcl1/AA) already. Apparently Python optimizes that when `byte` is `0`. Btw, I only ...

Comment: ... know this *"count leading zeros in SHA256 hash*" from bitcoin mining, where I think you just want to be fast and aren't worried about timing attacks. Do you know it from some other context where you *are* worried about timing attacks?

Comment: @KellyBundy nope, I don't know of any use-cases for counting leading zeroes in hashes. I just start by assuming that all attacks matter to protect against until I have positive knowledge/reasoning that something is safe to ignore.

Comment: Anyway I've updated my answer to deprecate my own attempt at wrangling Python into data independent execution from within Python. There's no way to defeat arbitrary optimizations unless the programming language lets you talk about and control runtime as a side effect.

Comment: Tried a few more values on your full last solution, with all bytes being `16` it's [12% slower](https://tio.run/##jZLdasMwDIXv8xSig5JsvUhaGKWQvsjYghMrrVhiB1sd614@s@K0kIuO@c76@c5B0nDlszW7/eDGsXW2B6YeiYH6wToGhwMqThKNLTT2YrjqUGkyp@oHnUVfkanqK6NPtWKVHRKAWAcl5PJ5gtop05w79B5WneLmvIJe@U9gC57tEMsDcer1TF0n0KVMoBWSbq0DkQMyIIJTD8wJMhq/JePwC51HnQblE6b7LLvXyatJ3KUT53iMbRmso8LtLX031mhiskZ1K6B2QpAHMbdAk58MB7xUfDxGdteg2zjsMYwqDixgDaJGvSDG3Et5R68fzegPqWnsM8oaaMl5hkI8LrQeDX99V5dqh3xxJtLCYYQtyHriEbzl7xk8w267uQWK1zmSJLIjKb8tz0s8GpCF9GTSeG5pp/paq8N/Lm4zn2i5zTdgLn2NrizyPMsm7uDIcMpBKMRCgbSIx3H8BQ) than with all `0`.

Comment: @KellyBundy cheers, thanks for testing it out more thoroughly.

Comment: @KellyBundy Can you test C extensions easily enough in your benchmarks? I just added a very basic one.

Comment: No idea, never tried that. But tried a ["constant time" one](https://tio.run/##dVLLboMwELzzFXsK0NDICYoURSI/0E/oA5mwpCuBQbapkv586rUhSQ/xjd3ZnZkdhov97lW@G/T12ui@A0sdkgXqhl5b0DigtFFUYwOd1fKIo05qaWW6jwDg2I/KQgGCP4ylti1JlS3KmtSp/EXdo3HtNbebXkN1sQikgDf4BTA1SNV45o7GH9QG60RLdcJkl6Y3HL@KmC7xew6HMJbCIjDMj4yndkCGf/1vBsnL4oZaPBP@OPXM2@K2h9Ea7ahVoAg3e8O2vTwcjC/AF6nij7NYx7D0p/AdXyaVkLIrTqJkk4atmgziik5xmnogOaBZNc57Eq/jDPJQnksbV6JQmvQQvELu9DgmT@L3vovPFF4g32RzYbPdTqUo4kyaUR05kjn3LLgJPgbtdCYMWZWlkh2WpTMT7@PAzPPMN4dteO89SQ6xc17D75W0sqtqufeM4VjZ9OcVGyEEUDOJMUECYGsQcpGBGrsKdbEVYjrOXZt1lGs3nXkBbPd6/QM) myself now.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's good intuition, and I imagine it helps against the most blatant/direct timing measurements! Nice. I think it wouldn't be entirely safe against side-channels though (f.e. branch predictor state) because each call of `.find` individually is still doing data-dependent branching (plus `bin` itself presumably has data-dependent branches).

Comment: @KellyBundy actually, maybe you've beaten `bin` data-dependency enough to make stuff like branch predictor state not matter (that's largely the responsibility of other layers to protect against after all, like the CPU/kernel).

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah the only thing I can see is a branch predictor or higher-level JIT optimizer realizing that the branch inside the second `.find` can never match a `2`. But I'm not enough of an expert to say off the top of my head if that's enough speedup for someone to meaningfully measure it.

Comment: Cryptographers worry about these kinds of branches even in C/machine code as possible sources of timing attacks though, so I'd guess it's still enough to be real risk.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's constant time. But at least it's pretty fast and seems to only vary by ~0.4% (except for wild outliers). Getting such close times on a public shared server is pretty impressive already :-). Possibly the instability of the machine has a bigger impact than the data.

Comment: @KellyBundy right, it's very impressive!

Answer (score 1):

`.hexdigest()` returns a string, so your `hex` variable is a string.

I'm going to call it `h` instead, because `hex` is a builtin python function.

So you have:

```
h = "0000094e7cc7303a3e33aaeaba76ad937603d4d040064f473a12f10ab30a879f"
```

Now this is a *hexadecimal* string. Each digit in a hexadecimal number gives you four bits in binary. Since this has five leading zeros, you already have `5 * 4 = 20` leading zeros.

```
nzeros = 0
for c in h:
    if c == "0": nzeros += 4
    else: break
```

Then, you need to count the leading zeros in the binary representation of the first non-zero hexadecimal digit. This is easy to get: A `number` has `math.floor(math.log2(number)) + 1` binary digits, i.e. `4 - (math.floor(math.log2(number)) + 1)` leading zeros if it's a hexadecimal digit, since they can only have a max of 4 bits. In this case, the digit is a `9` (`1001` in binary), so there are zero additional leading zeros.

So, modify the previous loop:

```
nzeros = 0
for c in h:
    if c == "0": nzeros += 4
    else: 
        digit = int(c, base=16)
        nzeros += 4 - (math.floor(math.log2(digit)) + 1)
        break

print(nzeros) # 20
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had trouble determining the leading zeroes for the first nonzero digit but this works perfectly.

Comment: This is a good answer in that it is informative and I *trust* correct (I have to trust, because I can't justify the time to thoroughly rigorously mentally check, because of what I'm about to critique), but if I was maintaining production code or doing a code review, I would rage if I had to interpret/verify logic first counting leading zeroes in hex and then the leading zeroes of the most significant non-zero nibble. The complexity (number of things complected together), the number of steps, the number of functions whose behavior needs to be mentally loaded up - all larger than necessary.

Comment: An alternative for the `else` code: `nzeros += sum(c < d for d in '842')`. Though I still think doing this with the hex string is a mistake anyway.

Comment: Or use `.bit_length()` on the digit int, as I've done in my `Kelly2` now. Using bytes makes everything faster/simpler here :-P